# Inserting entity doesn't update Key field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, graphdiff

I'm trying to insert a detached entity into database using GraphDiff.

It goes something like :

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Foo foo) {
    var newFoo = fooBusiness.AddObject(foo);
    if (newFoo != null) {
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetOperation", new { id = newFoo.Id }, newFoo);
    }
    return Conflict();
}
```

And my `addObject` function basically is :

```
public Foo AddObject(Foo entity)
{
    UpdateGraph(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return entity;
}

public override void UpdateGraph(Foo entity)
{
    DataContext.UpdateGraph(entity, map => map
        .AssociatedCollection(e => e.Bars)
        .AssociatedEntity(e => e.Baz)
    );
}
```

Problem comes when I try to get the Id of newly added Foo, it remains empty (0).

Shouldn't EF update object to what it actually inserted in database ? Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found out right before posting the question that `UpdateGraph` had a return type and that I did not use it..

If you don't use the returned entity, the entities states will be well updated but the entity tracking will totally fail.

Changing my `AddObject` to this solved the problem :

```
public Foo AddObject(Foo entity)
{
    entity = UpdateGraph(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return entity;
}

public override Foo UpdateGraph(Foo entity)
{
    return DataContext.UpdateGraph(entity, map => map
        .AssociatedCollection(e => e.Bars)
        .AssociatedEntity(e => e.Baz)
    );
}
```

Comment: you should accept your own answer so people know it's solved.

Comment: @RaduPascal I will when the 2 days period for accepting a self  answer will be over :)

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware of that.